# c# Hide external process trayicon

Tags: process, hide, external, trayicon

I have a program in C# for auto run a webcam program for use my NTB as security cam...
I run a BooruCam in program and check title for check error with upload image to server. all is ok but I don't know how I hide in tray this external program icon. I know process name or id of boorucam.
my app is in console and I can't find nothing for look and inspirate.

Comment: Did you try to start the process hidden?

Comment: No..

code here
[code]
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   startInfo.FileName = Patch + OpenFile + ".exe";
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Try starting your process hidden.

```
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

A full example can be found [here](http://joshcellsoftwares.com/open-source/start-process-hidden-in-dot-net/).